# IE Not Updating Asp.Net MVC3 Partial View

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-11

I have a page that contains a div for a partial view that is being returned via an ajax request.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'CompleteSessions',
        success: function (data) {

            var selector = $('#complete-session-section');
            if (data.length > 0) {
                selector.html(data);
            }
            else {
                selector.append($(document.createElement('option')).html('No assessments'));
            }
        }
    });
```

The partial view itself has a model and constructs a combobox based on the number of returned sessions.

```
    @using SmartQWeb.Models.Entities
@using SmartQWeb.Runtime;
@model IEnumerable<Session>


<span class="dropdown">
<select style="width: 75%" id = "complete-session-selector">
    <option id="-1">Select a Session</option>
    @foreach (Session session in Model.OrderByDescending(date=>date.StartTime))
    {
        if (session.Assessment != null)
        {
            <option id="@session.AssessmentId" value="@session.Id" title="Administered by: @session.User.Name" data-assessmentId="@session.AssessmentId">@session.Participant.AliasLookup.AliasId - @session.StartTime  </option>
        }
    }
</select>


</span>
```

The problem is that, only for IE, the dropdown does not get properly updated when the page is first loaded.  I have to hit F5 (sometimes control F5) to refresh and see the new entries in the combobox.  This is not a problem for Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default 'type' argument for jQuery ajax requests is 'GET' which IE will cache.  You can disable caching in your ajax request or switch to a 'POST' to prevent this --

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    cache: false
});
```